# Is there any relationship between Aquinas teaching on the analogical knowledge of God and Christ teaching in parables?

Tags: catholicism, names-of-god, thomas-aquinas, parables, special-revelation

Is there any relationship between Aquinas teaching on the analogical knowledge of God and Christ teaching in parables (ie. via analogies)?

Comment: I've always thought so, but I don't know of any academic sources.

Comment: Just slapping the "catholicism" tag on a question doesn't really suffice for making a question on topic.

Comment: @curiousdannii Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Given the fact that most "off topic" complaints are scope or so-called "truth question" concerns, specifying a Church usually does suffice for making a question on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Parables & Metaphors

To speak parabolically is to speak in metaphors, and metaphors pertain to poetry, "the least (*infima*) of all the sciences" because it "makes use of metaphors for the sake of (*propter*) representation" ([*Summa Theologica* I q. 1 a. 9](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP001.html#FPQ1A9THEP1) arg./ad 1).

Unlike analogy, metaphors can be used to conceal knowledge (or reveal it):

> [Matthew 13:10](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=13&l=10-#x)-11
> Why speakest thou to them [the multitudes] in parables [and openly to the Apostles]? […] Because to you [the Apostles] it is given to know the mysteries of the kingdom of heaven: but to them it is not given.

[St. Thomas's commentary on Matthew](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5049) [13:3](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=13&l=3-#x):

> ***And he spoke to them many things in parables.*** The reason is twofold[: that]
>
> 1. […] by parables of this kind, sacred things would be hidden from the unbelievers, lest they blaspheme: for it was said above, “Give not that which is holy to dogs” ([[Mt.] 7, 6](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=7&l=6-#x)). […]
> 2. spiritual things are hidden; for that reason, they cannot fully be made known through temporal things, hence, they have to be made known through different things; “I wish that God would speak with thee, and would open his lips to thee, that he might shew thee the secrets of wisdom” ([Job 11, 5](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=20&ch=11&l=5-#x)-6).

Metaphor is "improper [supposition](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/supposition-logic)" according to John of St. Thomas. This means "that a word is predicated of something which does not fall under what the word signifies." (McInerny [*Logic of Analogy*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4403) p. 146).

## Analogy

Thesis 4 of the [24 Thomistic Theses](http://scholastic.us.to/24Thomisticpart2.htm) states:

> **Thesis IV.**
>
> **Ens, quod denominatur ab esse, non univoce de Deo ac de creaturis dicitur, nec tamen prorsus aequivoce, sed analogice, analogia tum attributionis tum proportionalitis.**
>
> **Being, which derives its name from existence, is not predicated univocally of God and creatures; nor yet merely equivocally, but analogically, by the analogy both of attribution and of proportionality.**
>
> *Commentary*: If the actuality of existence is in God a Pure Act and is in creatures an Act mixed with Potency, Being cannot be predicated of God and creatures in an identical way [**univocally**]: God is self-existing, creatures have their existence from God. Still, because the effect in some manner reproduces its cause, Being does not belong to God and creatures in a totally different sense [**equivocally**]. Being, as predicated of God and creatures is an **analogous** term. Its analogy is first that of attribution, since Being appertains to creatures as far as they have it from God, to whom it appertains by essence; and is secondly that of proportionality, since the actuality of existence is intrinsic to God and creatures as existing beings. [[*Summa Theologiae*, Iª q. 13 a. 5](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP013.html#FPQ13A5THEP1); [*Contra Gentiles*, lib. 1 cap. 32](https://isidore.co/aquinas/ContraGentiles1.htm#32) et [cap. 33](https://isidore.co/aquinas/ContraGentiles1.htm#33) et [cap. 34](https://isidore.co/aquinas/ContraGentiles1.htm#34); [*De potentia*, q. 7 a. 7](https://isidore.co/aquinas/QDdePotentia7.htm#7:7)]

Cf. McInerny's [*Aquinas & Analogy*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5064) and [this constructive criticism of it](https://iteadthomam.blogspot.com/2010/10/why-cajetans-interpretation-of-aquinass.html); its ch. 6 is on "Metaphor and Analogy".

<sub>cf. also: "[Are analogical middle terms sufficient for a valid demonstration?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/21380/2014)," a distinctive feature of Thomism, and [St. Thomas on the three types of predication from his *De Principiis Naturæ*](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/39748/2014)</sub>

Comment: @Thom [Rom. 1:20](https://aquinas.cc/196/198/~388) is the classic verse on knowing God by analogy from creation. Also, Vatican I's [_Dei Filius_](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds2.v.ii.i.html#v.ii.i-p17.13) on faith & reason mentions analogy.